# Circular graph for internal maven multi modules project dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a project containing maven multi modules and I'm working on Intellij.
In this project, i have 10 modules, each one contains multiple sub modules.
Example :

```
module-a
    sub-module-a-1
    sub-module-a-2
    sub-module-a-3
    sub-module-a-4
    sub-module-a-5
module-b
    sub-module-b-1
    sub-module-b-2
```

Each sub module depends on 1 or more other sub modules

Example : sub-module-a-1 depends on sub-module-b-2

How can I generate a circular diagram to show these dependencies in an Intellij diagram without libraries (only project dependencies) ?

Comment: This
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-module-dependencies-diagram.html
might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but it generates all the dependencies... with technical dependencies. It's not what I want to do. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to display only the dependencies between the Project's Modules?
Make sure "Libraries" and "Test Dependencies" options are disabled for the Diagram.
Can you share a screenshot with an example of what's being displayed and what you would like to omit from the Diagram?

Comment: Yes, I want to show only project's modules. Thank you, i'll try to disable libraries and test deps.